# Object lifetime issue with range-based for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, auto, object-lifetime

I'm currently converting my code to C++11 and having trouble with the following range-based for loop (FWIW, the same code ran just fine before with BOOST for_each).

The `mLibraryFiles` member (STL vector) is part of a singleton instance and **guaranteed** to exist after the method returns, however when the caller inspects the returned object it contains only garbage.

Debugging through it appears to turn from expected content to garbage just after returning from the method so I suppose I must have gotten something wrong about how the C++11 range-based loop actually works:

```
Entry* FindEntry(string inName)
{  Entry *rs = NULL;

   for (auto libraryEntry : mLibraryFiles)
   {
      if (libraryEntry.filename.compare(inName) == 0)
      {
         rs = &libraryEntry;
         break;
      }
   }

   return rs;
}
```

I would have expected that the `libraryEntry` variable represents the actual objects in the `mLibraryFiles` vector?

Any insights much appreciated!
(compiler is LLVM 5.0 though I doubt this matters..)

Comment: `libraryEntry` is a *copy* of the element of `mLibraryFiles`. Use `for (auto& libraryEntry : mLibraryFiles)` instead.

Comment: llvm is not currently at version 3.4. You probably mean clang?

Comment: @Nil Apple uses a separate version numbering scheme for their LLVM releases. (And yes, [LLVM is currently at version 3.4](http://llvm.org/releases/3.4/docs/ReleaseNotes.html).) Apple's releases don't necessarily coincide with upstream LLVM releases, so they use a different numbering scheme to "avoid confusion."

Comment: @Nil Yes, sorry for the confusion - version as shown in Xcode 5, which states *Apple LLVM 5.0*

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++11 range based loop: get item by value or const reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176104/c11-range-based-loop-get-item-by-value-or-const-reference)

Comment: And since I'm here typing stuff, I tell you that (assuming `libraryEntry.filename` is a `std::string`) you can replace `libraryEntry.filename.compare(inName) == 0` with the equivalent `libraryEntry.filename == inName`.

Comment: @Casey True - thanks for pointing that out! Still way too much `char[]` code in this project waiting to be 'upgraded' to actual objects..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The values from your vector are copied to libraryEntry in the loop, so you have a pointer to copied value which no longer exists after the loop. Use `auto& libraryEntry`.

Answer (score 4):

Declare `libraryEntry` as `auto&` otherwise its a temporary copy which lifetime is bound to the for-loop. Thats why I prefer to write the actual type of the object instead of `auto`

Comment: herb sutter says use auto whenever you can and avoid using the actual type. It gives you the flexibility of typedef for free.

Comment: Writing the actual type, also without a `&`, will be just as bad.