# What does `auto && e` do in range-based for-loops?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, universal-reference, forwarding-reference

Assuming my current rule when programming with range-based loops says

> Use `for(auto const &e :...)` or `for(auto &e:...)` when possible over `for(auto a: ...)`.

I base this on my own experience and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176104) for example.

But after reading about the new [terse for loops](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/12/details-about-some-of-the-new-c-language-features.aspx) I wonder, should I not replace my `&` in my rule with `&&`? As written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480) this looks like the [Meyers' Universal References](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

So, I ask myself, should my new rule either be

> Use `for(auto const &&e :...)` or `for(auto &&e:...)` when possible ...

or does that not always work and therefore should rather be the quite complicated one

> Check if `for(auto const &&e :...)` or `for(auto &&e:...)` is possible, then consider `for(auto const &e :...)` or `for(auto &e:...)`, and only when needed do not use references.

Comment: `auto &&` always works. That's why it's "universal". If necessary, the deduced type will be qualified.

Comment: `const auto&&` is not a forwarding reference, it's const rvalue reference

Comment: and the rest is explained in [N3853](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3853.htm) and [What is the advantage of using universal references in range-based for loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130708/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-universal-references-in-range-based-for-loops)

Comment: I think it was Herb Sutter in "Back to basics" who said: writing `const auto&&` is almost always wrong.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet I found the talk slides [https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2014/tree/master/Presentations/Back%20to%20the%20Basics!%20Essentials%20of%20Modern%20C%2B%2B%20Style] but I can not find your reference. He says "for local variables", but I think in "auto for loops" it maay be an exception. Do you have the exact or better  reference?

Comment: I could be wrong, maybe it was Scott Meyers in "Type deduction and why you care".

Comment: @Bulletmagnet Well, I'll buy Scott's new book soon anyway. But I have his old C++11 slides and I don't think he mentions it there. I can follow Herbs argument about local variables, but I wonder auto-for is not just an exception then -- or why  N3853 seems to disagree.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet it was STL during [CppCon'14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTeKf5Oek2c&t=47m4s)

Comment: @PiotrS. No, it is obviously not a "forwarding reference" as in `template<class T> void func(T&&)`. But it seems to me that "reference collapsing rules" do apply here, still. So I assumed one can call this "universal reference", informally. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Bulletmagnet Thanks, STL was it, alright. Now I got it, you refer to the `const`, mainly. I missed that. Of course, thank you.

Comment: @PiotrS. Thank you that is a very important information. I was under a misconception, then. That definitely makes the difference.

Comment: @towi only `auto&&`, with **no** qualifiers, is universal/forwarding reference. None of the following are universal references: `const auto&&`, `volatile auto&&`, `const volatile auto&&`, `auto*&&`, and so forth...

Comment: @PiotrS. 
Cunningham's Law states "the best way to get the right answer on the Internet is not to ask a question, it's to post the wrong answer."

Comment: @towi no, it only states that `auto` used as a type specifier uses the same rules as template argument deduction procedure, in other words `const auto&& = x;` is the same as `template<class T> void f(const T&& t); f(x);`.

Comment: @PiotrS. Yes, I know, but doesn't exactly your example imply that it behaves like a F/URef? {Damn, how do I move this comment thread to a wiki discussion? :-) }

Comment: @towi no, because neither `T` in `template<class T> void f(const T&&)` is a forwarding reference, nor `const auto&&` is. The fact that `T&&` occurs in parameter declaration does not imply it is forwarding reference. Only *pure* `T&&` with **no qualifiers** like `const` or `volatile` is forwarding reference, meaning it has to be `template<class T> void f(T&&)` or `auto&&`, and ***never*** `const T&&` or `const auto&&`

Comment: @PiotrS. Alright, I believe you because you state it so firmly. But I would feel better about it, if you could point me to a reference (no pun intended).

Comment: @towi: §14.8.2.1 [temp.deduct.call]/p3. you seem to still be misleading the difference between `auto&` and `auto&&`, as well as `const auto&` and `const auto&&`. they have completely different meaning.

Answer (score 16):

When and if you should use `auto&&` in for loops has been explained very nicely by Howard Hinnant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13130795/472245).

This leaves the question what `x` in

```
auto &&x = ...expr...
```

actually is. And it is handled as if there there were a function template definition

```
template <class U> void f(U&& u);
```

and the type of `x` is deduced by the same rules as `u` [§7.1.6.4.(7)].

This means it is **not** handled as a RValue Reference, but as a "Universal/Forwarding Reference" -- the "[Reference Collapsing Rules](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html)" apply.

This also holds for

```
const auto &&x = ...expr...
```

as the example in §7.1.6.4.(7) states, at least for `const auto &x`.

But, as PiotrS says in the questions comments, any qualifiers nullifies the URef-ness:

> no, because neither `T` in `template<class T> void f(const T&&)` is a forwarding reference, nor `const auto&&` is. The fact that `T&&` occurs in parameter declaration does not imply it is forwarding reference. Only pure `T&&` with no qualifiers like `const` or `volatile` is forwarding reference, meaning it has to be `template<class T> void f(T&&)` or `auto&&`, and never `const T&&` or `const auto&&`

Comment: For Forward reference, it should be `template <class U> void f(U&& u);` not `template <class U> void f(const U& u);`

Comment: "nullifies the URef-ness" is highly misleading... reference collapsing happens for `const T&&` just as it does for `T&&`.  It is no longer "universal" because half the types in the universe (the ones not `const` qualified) cannot be matched, but it behaves much the same.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's not just qualification. A `const auto&&` declarator or the `u` in `template<class U> void f(const U&& u);` can never automatically deduce type from any lvalue. The special rule which makes it valid for a true forwarding reference (and indirectly for the exact type `auto&&`) no longer applies.