# Why std::move didn't move

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Wrote the following code in vs13:

```
std::vector<std::string> myvector(1000);
std::fill(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), "Hello World");
std::vector<std::string> pushto;
for (auto s: myvector)
    pushto.push_back(std::move(*s));
```

Works but didn't move, it called string copy ctor instead. `myvector` still had his "Hello World"s at the end.
Using regular c++ 98 iteration like this:

```
 std::vector<std::string> myvector(1000);
 std::fill(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), "Hello World");
 std::vector<std::string> pushto;
 for (auto s = myvector.begin(); s != myvector.end();s++)
    pushto.push_back(std::move(*s));
```

Actually worked, and move was called. `myvector` strings were empty. 
Why the first more modern notation doesnt work?

Comment: Does the first example really compile? I don't think there should be the `*` in `std::move(*s)`.

Comment: Note that noone ever said that a move should erase the original. After moving, the original is in a *valid but unspecified* state. Even if you put the `&` in place, it's perfectly valid (and, imho, sometimes desired) for the original object to have the same value(s) as the new one (i.e., same as before till modified).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example you are using `for (auto s: myvector)`, `s` in this case is a copy of the value in the current iteration. to accomplish what you want, you should do it by reference - `for (auto& s: myvector)`.

Note that the string is not guaranteed to be emptied after `std::move`, this call just casts its argument to a rvalue reference (`&&`). other functions (such as `std::vector::push_back`) which have an overload for rvalue referece arguments **might** free their argumnet resources.

Comment: .. and even then, you're not guaranteed to have the old string emptied.

Comment: Indeed, but this is the right way to use `std::move` (and it will probably be emptied in the OP's compiler since it got emptied in the second example)

Comment: Right way: definitely, I agree with you. Excepting emptying: that's implementation detail of the class *and* of the compiler (both, not either).

Comment: @orenshochat your welcome :) If this answer helped you, you should mark it as accepted (using the green tick v)

Answer (score 3):

As @Polikdir said, the copying comes from the copy you made at `(auto s: myvector)`. One way is to use the range-for loop, with `&&` (forwarding reference) or `&` (normal reference):

```
for (auto & val : myvector)
    pushto.push_back(std::move(val));
```

Not well known, but there's a dedicated algorithm for moving objects between containers. It's actually also called [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move).

```
std::move(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(pushto));
```

**edit:**

q: *Since std::move just casts to rvalue reference is it really needed? Isn't std::move in this case just redundant?* No, because a variable (such as val) can not be an r-value reference. That's why we need to call `std::forward<T>` on universal references.

Also note: [What does `auto && e` do in range-based for-loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991393/what-does-auto-e-do-in-range-based-for-loops)

Comment: Since `std::move` just casts to rvalue reference is it really needed? Isn't `std::move` in this case just redundant?

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful solution