# C++: print out vector elements in a set container

Tags: c++, vector

I want to print out the vector element in a set container. I did the code as follows:

```
int main() {
  vector<int> aa = {3, 2, 1, 1};
  vector<int> bb = {5, 1, 7, 9};

  set<vector<int>> myset; // setVector

  myset.insert(aa);
  myset.insert(bb);

  for (auto elem : myset) {
    cout << elem << ", ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However, this code can not print out the vector: `(3, 2, 1, 1)` and `(5, 1, 7, 9)`.

Comment: Thanks for helping edit the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto elem: myset` here `elem` refers to the `vectors`.

to print out the contents of the vectors do this:

```
 for (auto elem : myset)
 {
      for(auto x:elem) // elem is each vector
      {
           std::cout << x << " ";
      }
       std::cout << std::endl;   
  }
```

Here you iterate over the `vectors` in the inner `for loop`.
Also, you might want to use `auto&` in the loop if you are updating elements or to prevent copies since then you get a reference.

Comment: copies for the vector objects so 2 in this contrived example.

Comment: I accept it since it is the first solution and works.

Comment: @PYA, `O(nm)` where `n = size of set` and `m = size of  vector`. you can [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176127/8012206) more to this post.

Comment: @codekaizer hmm vector copy is much more expensive than an integer copy so I don't think that really presents a good picture of how expensive copies might be. Will be very different for large n and small m and small n and large m but i do get your point :)

Comment: that's why I didn't downvote. :) was just pointing that you *might* as well not work with copies if *not necessarily needed*.

Comment: appreciate it :)

Answer (score 5):

you should also loop your `vector` elements inside `myset`.

```
for (auto const &elem : myset) {    // loop set elements
   for (auto const &v: elem) {      // loop vector elements
      std::cout << v << ", ";       // print each vector element
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to print which you tried. You should overload << operator.

Also you may use like this.

```
for (auto elem : myset) {
  cout << "("; 
  for(auto item:elem)
   {
       cout << item << ",";
   }
   cout << ")"; 
   cout << endl;   
}
```

Comment: why do you need to overload?

Comment: if you print whatever you want.

Comment: here you won't need to overload `operator<<` since `item` is an `int`

Comment: as far as I understand elem is an `vector <int>` instead of `int`

Comment: @Yılmazedis, true. was just pointing out that OP doesn't need to overload if iterating over primitive types.