# Vector with reference

Tags: c++, reference

I am learning C++ and I have problem to understand why this works. I understand that a reference is just synonym for a certain object. But I do not understand why this

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
for (auto &i : v)      //using reference
    i *= i;
```

outputs `1,4,9` and this

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    for (auto i : v)   //without using reference
        i *= i;
```

outputs `1,2,3`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: this answers you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176104/c11-range-based-loop-get-item-by-value-or-reference-to-const

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same reason why:

```
int a=2;

int &b=a;

b=3;
```

why this ends up setting `a` to 3, but:

```
int a=2;

int b=a;

b=3;
```

`a` is still `2`, and only `b` is 3.

The vector itself is irrelevant, this has to do with the basic concept of what a reference is. A reference creates an alias for the referenced object. A "non-reference" creates a new object. `auto &i` creates a reference. `auto i` creates a new object and initializes it by copying its value from another object, in this case each value in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

The reference is actually a reference to a certain object in memory.

So when you do `auto &i` you create a reference to an object (in that case it is an element from the vector).
Any operations are performed on the referenced object - i.e. the element of the vector. `i *= i` changes the value of the element, because `i` is the reference to this element.

And when you do `auto i` you create a new variable (object) which is being stored on a stack. That object only lives in the scope of the for loop. So the changes made to it do not affect any other data.

Hope this helps.