# Why I am able to modify using constant range based loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number = 10;
    map<int*, int> intmap;
    intmap.insert(pair<int*, int>(&number, 1));
    
    for (auto const &  x : intmap)
    {
        (*x.first)++;
        
    }

    for (auto const &  x : intmap)
    {
        cout << (*x.first) << "::" << x.second; //prints 11::1
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176127/12684120) its mentioned that

> Choose auto const &x when you want to work with original items and
> will not modify them.

but in the above program, I am able to modify it. Looks like the x in for loop is constant pointer rather than a pointer to constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not modifying map or map elements. You are modifying pointee, and there's nothing to prevent you from doing that (apart from changing map type).

The type of `x` is `const std::pair<int* const, int>&`, or a reference to const pair. Notice that the first element of the pair is a constant pointer, but **it is not pointing to a constant value**.
With this, you are not allowed to modify either pair elements (`x.first++` and `x.second++` would both fail).
However, since `x.first` is a const pointer to non-const int, `*x.first` is just a regular `int&`, no const here, and you can increment it.

If you want to prevent such situation, you can change map key type to `const int*`, aka. *pointer to const int*.

```
map<const int*, int> intmap;
```

---

Also note that you cannot modify key (or the first value in pair) even with non-const reference:

```
for (auto &  x : intmap)
{
    x.first++; //fails
}
```

Comment: Understood, but for map<int,int> the for loop pair is <const int, int> then for the pointer key value shouldn't it to be const*int rather that int * const ?

Comment: @samnactionThe key (the pointer) is what's const so `int * const` is correct. If the pointed-to object was const it would be `const int *`. The placement of `const` before or after the asterisk is important.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Erm, `int*` most certainly converts to `const int*`. Did you mean to say "adding `const` to `int*` gives `int *const` and not `int const*`"? This is why (IMO) `const` should always be written *after* the type... (and that way it also comes at the correct position in the reading order)

Answer (score 0):

Similar case:

```
int x = 0;
int* const p = &x;
*p = 42;
```

A constant pointer cannot be modified, but you can use it to modify what it points to. Only a `const int*`, pointer to constant `int`, would prevent that.