# How to initialize a vector of struct inside another vector of struct?

Tags: c++

I try to initialize structures of vectors that contains vector:

```
    struct productionCanvas
    {
        int canvasID;
        int indexXmlJob;
    };
    
    struct productionArea
    {
        int areaID;
        std::vector<productionCanvas> canvasList;
    };
```

The first level is correctly initialized but not the second one:

```
    int areaIncr=0;
    int canvasIncr=0;
    std::vector<productionArea> production;
    
    int addArea()
    {
        productionArea area{};
    
        areaIncr++;
        area.areaID = areaIncr;
        area.canvasList = {};
        production.push_back(area);
        return areaIncr;
    }
    
    int addCanvas(int job)
    {
        productionCanvas canvas{};
    
        canvasIncr++;
        canvas.canvasID = canvasIncr;
        canvas.indexXmlJob = job;
        for (productionArea area : production)
        {
            if (area.areaID == areaIncr)
            {
                area.canvasList.push_back(canvas);  // this line is triggered
                break;
            }
        }
        // Check if correctly push_back
        for (productionArea area : production)
        {
            for (productionCanvas canvas : area.canvasList)
            {
                // This line is never triggered, why ?
            }
        }
        return canvasIncr;
    }
    
    addArea();  // area correctly inserted
    addCanvas(1);  // canvas not inserted inside area
    .
```

There is no return value of the push_back function, so I cannot know why it's not pushed back!
It seemed that it does not work like Qt-QVector.

How to initialize these struct?

Comment: you posted bogus code. `for each (productionArea area in production)` is not valid C++

Comment: Are you sure that the code compiles? `for each (productionArea area in production)` is not valid c++.

Comment: Please post real code.

Comment: I have converted to real C++ code, it's compiling and running on my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zero-initialize any POD struct or array by simply adding `{}`:

```
productionArea area{};
// Or
productionArea area = {};
// Or
auto area = productionArea{};
```

Unless you are working in C/C++ environment, there is no need for `typedef struct` in C++. The symbol namespaces are not separate. This is equal to your current code:

```
struct productionCanvas_def
{
    int canvasID;
    int indexXmlJob;
} productionCanvas;
```

You can even initialize each member:

```
struct foo{
    int a{2};
    int a{4};
};
```

But then it is no longer POD.

### After the question has been edited

The problem is here:

```
for (productionArea area : production) // <-- The `area` is a copy of 
                                       //     the one in the container.
        {
            if (area.areaID == areaIncr)
            {
                area.canvasList.push_back(canvas);  // this line is triggered
                break;
            }
        }
```

To modify elements in place, you have to use references `for(productionArea &area : production)`

Comment: Thanks @Quimby I did as you says but I'm still not able to initialize the area.canvasList by push_back(canvas)  (at the line:  // this line is triggered )

Comment: @Chrigou Oh, I see where you problem is, your `for` loops modify the copies. You need to use `(productionArea &area : production)` to change the `area` inside the `production` container.

Comment: @Chrigou See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176104/c11-range-based-loop-get-item-by-value-or-reference-to-const , the recap in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Quimby, finally it works very well now!

Comment: @Chrigou Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't look like c++ , but the below code wiil not run as  your  canvasList with empty in  addArea

```
area.canvasList = {};
```

Comment: Seems to be the problem, but I don't understand where is the error, it compile and run without crash. Is there a solution how to initialize this structure?