# Change the field of a derived class object but the change was recovered after returning

Tags: c++, abstract-class, derived-class, mutation

I override the `create` function.

```
void IBlock::create() {
    Cell a;
    a.setCoords(0, 3);
    a.setblank(false);
    Cell b;
    b.setCoords(1, 3);
    b.setblank(false);
    Cell c;
    c.setCoords(2, 3);
    c.setblank(false);
    Cell d;
    d.setCoords(3, 3);
    d.setblank(false);
    vector<Cell> row2;
    row2.push_back(a);
    row2.push_back(b);
    row2.push_back(c);
    row2.push_back(d);
    block.push_back(row2);
}
```

But when I try to change the coordinates of `IBlock` using `right` and `setX` in cell, and output their coordinates,

```
void Board::right() {
    bool movable = true;
    if (getCurrent() == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    for (auto ro : getCurrent()->block) {
        int x = ro.back().getX() + 1;
        int y = ro.back().getY();
        if (x >= col || (board[y][x])) {
            movable = false;
        }
    }
    if (movable) {
        for (auto ro : getCurrent()->block) {
            for (auto co : ro) {
                int x = co.getX();
                int y = co.getY();
                board[y][x] = false;
            }
        }

        for (auto ro : getCurrent()->block) {
            for (auto co : ro) {
                co.setX(co.getX() + 1);
                int x = co.getX();
                int y = co.getY();
                board[y][x] = true;
                cout << x << y << "!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
void Cell::setX(int a)
{
    this->x = a;
}
```

I get the coordinates as `13!23!33!43!`.
But when I get the coordinates back in main, I get the coordinates as `03!13!23!33!` just as the coordinates before the movement?

HOW CAN I MAKE THE CHANGE OF COORDINATES STAY? THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!

Comment: Can you show a [mre], that everyone can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce your problem? The two chunks of shown code mean very little to anyone who doesn't already know what the rest of this program looks like. There could be many kinds of reasons for this kind of a problem, so without a [mre] nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for (auto co : ro)` makes a copy of each iterated object rendering calls like `co.setX()` useless. It is like passing parameters by value. If you need your loop (function) to mutate the iterable's elements (arguments), bind them to a reference loop variable (parameter).

Use  `for (auto& co : ro)`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176127) for more details.

Same goes for `for (auto ro : getCurrent()->block)` loops, use `const auto&` to avoid extra copies.