# 'identifier undefined' in C++11 for-loop with USTRUCT

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, pointers, unreal-engine4

I am implementing logging functionality in Unreal Engine 4.27 (in C++). A key part of my code is a function that is called once per game-tick. This function is responsible for iterating over an array of actors that I would like to log data for, checking whether a new log entry should be written at this point in time and calling the necessary functions to do that.

I am iterating over elements of a TArray of UStructs: `LogObject->LoggingInfo = TArray<FActorLoggingInformation>`. This array is defined as a UProperty of LogObject. In the loop I have to change the values of the elements so I want to work with the original items and "label" the current item as "ActorLoggingInfo". I have seen this done [generally in cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176104/range-based-loop-get-item-by-value-or-reference-to-const) and also with [TArrays](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/blog/ranged-based-for-loops). And yet my code does not work, there is no error message, but `ActorLoggingInfo` is undefined, thus the if-condition is never met.

**This is the for-loop:**

```
for (FActorLoggingInformation& ActorLoggingInfo : LogObject->LoggingInfo) {
        if (ActorLoggingInfo.LogNextTick == true) {
            ActorLoggingInfo.LogNextTick = false;
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

**This is the definition of `FActorLoggingInformation`**:

```
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FActorLoggingInformation
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
    FActorLoggingInformation()
    {
    }

    FActorLoggingInformation(int32 LogTimer, AActor* Actor, FString LogName)
    {
        this->LogTimer = LogTimer;
        this->LogNextTick = false;
        ...
    }
    // Specifies Logging Frequency in ms
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, VisibleAnywhere)
    int32 LogTimer;
    bool LogNextTick;
    ...
};
```

**This is the debugger at run-time**:

[image: Debugger at run-time]

**Additional Notes**:

**1.** Something that consistently works for me is omitting the `&`, using:

`for (FActorLoggingInformation ActorLoggingInfo : LogObject->LoggingInfo)`

However, this is creating useless duplicates on a per-tick basis and complicates applying changes to the original objects from within in the for-loop, so it is not a viable option.

**2.** I have also tried `auto&` instead of `FActorLoggingInformation&` as used in the examples above, but I encountered the same issue, so I thought it would be best to be as explicit as possible.

I would be very thankful if you had any ideas how I can fix this :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you verified that the if condition is never met, but should be? Note that your undefined message is only from the debugger and it is for a local reference which is not necessarily implemented as a distinct object in its own right. It could be that there is no data RAM being used to implement it so no location for the debugger to inspect.

Comment: Wow! You're right, the if-condition was actually met, I just didn't notice. I simply assumed the debugger would present me with the absolute truth, so when stepping through the code and it never entered the if-body I assumed the code was never executed. Turns out it was simply the code inside the if-clause that did not work and because of the debugger it never occured to me to test for that^^ If you want to write up a proper answer yourself (for the XP) to formally resolve the question, I will accept it, otherwise I'll do it. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Avi Berger for helping me find my problem!
In fact, `ActorLoggingInfo` was actually never undefined and the code within the body of the if-clause was also executed (it just didn't do what it was intended to do).

When stepping through the code in the debugger it never showed the steps within the if-body and `ActorLoggingInfo` was shown as undefined so when no logs were written, I assumed it was something to do with that instead of my output function not working properly. So lesson learnt, do not blindly trust the debugger :)