# How to create more than one std::array dynamically in run time for updating them later

Tags: c++, arrays

I am very new to C++, so probably there are lots of different approaches to the problem that i want to solve, feel free to share your opinions and comments please.

```
void printCards(int cardCount)
{
    std::array<int, 15> cardArray{};

    std::array <std::array<int, 3>, 9> preparedCardArray{};

    std::cout << '\n';

    for (int i = 0;i < cardCount; i++)
    {
        cardArray = createCard();

        cardArray = sortCard(cardArray);

        preparedCardArray = prepareCardsForBingo(cardArray);

        cardToConsole(preparedCardArray);
        
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

In the code above i create an std::array which has a type

`std::array <std::array<int, 3>, 9>`

so when i create that std::array in runtime and store it, i can update that std::array later,  it is okay when `cardCount = 1`. I want know how to store std::arrays when card `cardCount > 1` count increases and all of the arrays needs to update in runtime.

[image]

-update
I am creating a console app. It is a bingo app after some numbers between 1 - 90 randomly picked. I need to remove those numbers from arrays and update them in console. So i need to reach those arrays that created before.

Comment: Please read and apply ["What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/11107541) As long as you do that, [you don't need to tell us that you are new to `X`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296391/11107541). Also, we don't do opinionated answers here. See [/hetp/dont-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: What is numberCountInCard, columnCountCard, rowCountCard? What is the definition of createCard?

Comment: It isn't really clear what the problem is. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @kiner_shah they all integers

Comment: Probably what you need is `std::vector` its like `std::array`, but with dynamic size.

Comment: If you want a function to effect an existing object, then you need to pass the object into the function as a parameter (probably by reference), not declare it inside the function.

Comment: @sklott okay i create 2 vectors then how can i call them in runtime what are their names ?

Comment: Same way you do with `std::array` the only difference that for `std::vector` you can change size in run-time, i.e. you can add elements when needed.

Comment: @UPinar The vector names are whatever you used when you declared them, same as any other variable. However my feeling is that vectors are not the answer you are looking for. Still not completely sure what the problem is however.

Comment: @sklott in this example when i create 2 arrays, how can i call them and update them in other function?

Comment: @UPinar Like I said, you must pass them into the function as parameters, not declare them in the function.

Comment: `sortCard` is a misleading choice of function name, at least for me. I'd expect a function with this name to have signature `void sortCard(std::array<int, 15>& arr)` instead of returning a value. If you return a value the function name doesn't tell you anything about whether an argument passed remains unmodified or not..

Comment: @UPinar Or alternatively you must pass them as parameter to that other function.

Comment: @UPinar Basically the solution it this. You have a variable in one function, and you want to access or update that variable in another function. The answer is to use function parameters to pass the variable (or a reference to it) from the first function to the second function.

Comment: @UPinar So based on the update, I think you have declared your arrays in the wrong place. Because the arrays are declared in the function `printCards` they are also destroyed in the function `printCards` and that is not what you want. Instead you must declare the arrays in another function (`main` presumably) and (again) use parameters to pass the arrays to your `printCards` function.

Comment: @john so how to declare arrays dynamically in main ?  what happens for example user wants 3 cards in runtime ?

Comment: @UPinar So each 'card' is an 2D array? Then you need a vector of 2D arrays `std::vector<std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 9>>` Sklott in the answer below seems to be on the right track.

Comment: yes each card is array but they have a  type of `std::array <std::array<int, 3>, 9>` so i think i need `std::vector<std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 9>>` is it possible ?

Comment: @UPinar Yes it's possible, it's perfectly normal. But use `using ...` declarations to make it a bit more understandable, again see sklott's answer.

Comment: @john first each card have type of `std::array<int, 15>;` then after some steps they both become `std::array <std::array<int, 3>, 9>` and then printed.  Okay i understand the using too..

Comment: @fabian i understand what did you mean maybe `sortedCard` will be better. Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of container to store your bingo card decks.

You can try something like this:

```
// At global scope (where you declared your functions)

using BingoCard = std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 9>;

// bingo cards generator
std::vector<BingoCard> createBingoCards(int cardCount);

// outputs cards to console
void printCards(const std::vector<BingoCard>& cards);

// outputs a single card to console.
void cardToConsole(const BingoCard& card);

// In a cpp file, define the generator

std::vector<BingoCard> createBingoCards(int cardCount)
{
    std::vector<BingoCard> result;
    result.reserve(cardCount);      // pre-allocate space for cards.

    for (int i = 0; i < cardCount; ++i)
    {
        auto cardArray = sortCard(createCard());
        result.push_back(prepareCardsForBingo(cardArray));
    }
    return result;
}

// and the print function. 

void printCards(const std::vector<BingoCard>& cards)
{
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (auto& card : cards)
    {
        cardToConsole(card);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just went  [Range based loop: get item by value or reference to const?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176127/17755777) from your answer.

Comment: In this case, the const keyword is redundant, since the parameter `cards` is itself const, the loop reference `card` into `cards` can only be const. Not adding a redundant const keyword to the loop makes for less clutter. :)

Comment: When in doubt, since you're learning, you could replace `auto&` with  `BingoCard&` and compile. The compiler should complain about not being able to convert from `const BingoCard&` to `BingoCard&`.

Comment: Yes i did try that.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you meant to do is something like this:

```
using CardType = std::array<int, 15>;
using PreparedCardType = std::array <std::array<int, 3>, 9>;

std::vector<CardType> createCards(int cardCount)
{
    std::vector<CardType> result;
    for (int i = 0;i < cardCount; i++) {
        result.push_back(createCard());
    }
    return result;
}

std::vector<PreparedCardType> prepareCards(const std::vector<CardType>& cards) {
    std::vector<PreparedCardType> result;
    std::transform(cards.begin(), cards.end(), std::back_inserter(result), prepareCardsForBingo);
    return result;
}

void void printCards(const std::vector<PreparedCardType>& prepCards)
{
    for (auto& card: prepCards) {
        cardToConsole(preparedCardArray);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

void some_func(int cardCount)
{
    auto cards = createCards(cardCount);
    auto prepCards = prepareCards(cards);
    printCards(prepCards);
}
```